# Elasticsearch Nest unit tests with Moq : fail to mock concrete class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, elasticsearch, moq

I need to mock some methods and properties in `Nest.IElasticClient` interface that is used in my repo.
As example I need to stub the `Indices.Exists()` method to return an `ExistsResponse` having an `Exists` property returning true.

The problem is that the concrete class has no interface implementation, nor setter on the Exists property, and is not declared virtual neither in Nest lib:

```c#
public class ExistsResponse : ResponseBase
{
    public ExistsResponse();
    public bool Exists { get; }
}

public ExistsResponse Exists(Indices index, Func<IndexExistsDescriptor, IIndexExistsRequest> selector = null);
```

So for the mocking I tried to set the property anyway on the concrete class, but it failed with all the following methods, I have no idea on how to do ...

```c#
/* Fail with exception :
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.Exists
    Non-overridable members (here: ExistsResponse.get_Exists) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
*/
    var mock1 = new Mock<ExistsResponse>();
    obj.SetupGet(f => f.Exists).Returns(true);

/* Fail with exception :
 System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: f => f.Exists
    Non-overridable members (here: ExistsResponse.get_Exists) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
*/
    var mock2 = Mock.Of<ExistsResponse>(x => x.Exists == true);

/* Fail with exception :
System.ArgumentException : Property set method not found.
*/
    var mock3 = new ExistsResponse();
    var property = typeof(ExistsResponse).GetProperty("Exists", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    property.SetValue(mock3, true);

/* Fail with exception :
System.NullReferenceException (setter is null)
*/
    var mock4 = new ExistsResponse();
    var setter = property.GetSetMethod(true);
    setter.Invoke(mock4, new object[] { true });


    // My Mock on the Indices.Exists method
    var elasticMock = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
    elasticMock
    .Setup(x => x.Indices.Exists(It.IsAny<string>(), null))
    .Returns(/*** my stubbed object here ***/); // <== how to stub the concrete class to return a ExistsResponse.Exists = true ?
```

My libs :

```
Nest 7.12.1
Moq 4.15.2
XUnit 2.4.1
.Net 5
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: With a constrained library like Moq, you can mock only virtual members. Therefore, you should mock the `IElasticClient` and return a ready-made `ExistsResponse` instance with the desired values.

Comment: Another way: use unconstrained libraries like TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes, Prig, Ionad.Fody, Pose, Harmony, MethodRedirect. They allow you to mock non-virtual members, as well as static, private, and so on.

Comment: As it is not possible to instantiate all classes of ES Responses all the time there is no way to use usual Mock frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually not good to mock what you don't own but if you want to mock elastic client responses the best approach will be to use InMemorryConnection, you can instantiate a new elasticClient with InMemorryConnection like this:

**InMemorry Elastic Client:**

```
var connection = new InMemoryConnection();
var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool, connection);
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Then you will need to fake the response and ask client to return it like below:

```
var response = new
{
    took = 1,
    timed_out = false,
    _shards = new
    {
        total = 2,
        successful = 2,
        failed = 0
    },
    hits = new
    {
        total = new { value = 25 },
        max_score = 1.0,
        hits = Enumerable.Range(1, 25).Select(i => (object)new
        {
            _index = "project",
            _type = "project",
            _id = $"Project {i}",
            _score = 1.0,
            _source = new { name = $"Project {i}" }
        }).ToArray()
    }
};

var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
var connection = new InMemoryConnection(responseBytes, 200); 
var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool, connection).DefaultIndex("project");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var searchResponse = client.Search<Project>(s => s.MatchAll());
```

You can find more information about InMemorryConnection [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/modifying-default-connection.html).

If you want to properly follow **don't mock what you don't own** you need to do following steps:

1. Wrap **`ElasticClient`** and all **`Request`** and **`Responses`** of ElasticClient in this library, then you can easily mock what you need.
2. You should test your wrapper class with Integration test to be sure your wrapped class work as expected.

**UPDATE:**

For mocking `Indices.Exists` you need only to send 200 OK so you only need to do this:

```
var connection = new InMemoryConnection(responseBytes, 200);
```

Comment: It's pretty similar to Integration Tests, doesn't it ? Any chance that I can get my ExistsResponse object replying that the index does exists that way ? (Indices.Exists = true)

Comment: This is not at all close to integration test becasue in integration test you will get the result back from Elastic but here you are going to get the result back from your json input, so instead of mocking directly the ElasticClient responses you need to mock the API call response. For does exists you need to find which API call send to ES and by creating fake API result you can easily mock it.

Comment: I updated my answer for getting true result for ndices.Exists.